# Can I put front end app in an external folder in Heroku and serve it on request?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku

I have a Node server and a React app compiled into its 'public' folder. My host is Heroku (a must for me).

My problem is that whenever I compile a new change on the React app I need to re-deploy the server.

Is there any way in Heroku to store the front end outside the server so that when I push a new code to the front end the server doesn't re-deploy?

Probably a bucket of some sort, or a server router that redirect calls depending on URL? Or any other solution?

Thanks!

**Edit:** I found an answer. It's called 'Bucketeer' in Heroku. It's the same S3 bucket from AWS. However, this is mainly for storing bulks of data, and it might not be fast enough to serving static app. So if you have any better idea I would appreciate sharing it.

Comment: I think no, because node server has not access to other host to transfer files

Comment: @Alex In different platforms (like AWS and others) one can buy storage space named bucket of volume and let Node read its static from it. It's about the host, not Node. But thanks!